# Why my Tailwind components library 'FlowBite' is not working?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

The tailwindCSS components library 'Flowbite" is not working after react has been upgraded to version18. I am following all the steps described in the documentation of 'Flowbite'. On the 6th step when I am importing the 'Flowbite' plugin in my `tailwind.config.js` file, I am getting this

```js
Could not find a declaration file for module 'flowbite/plugin'. 'D:/Web Development/Random Tests/Practice day task/test-app/node_modules/flowbite/plugin.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/flowbite` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'flowbite/plugin';`
```

What are the reasons and how to solve this?

Answer (score 5):

a work-around would be to add the following minified stylesheet inside the head tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flowbite@1.4.5/dist/flowbite.min.css" />
```

And include the following javascript file before the end of the body element:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flowbite@1.4.5/dist/flowbite.js"></script>
```

and also removing

```
import 'flowbite'
```

for myself this is a temporary fix till the library gets fixed.